# sending user input to div

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am here with a quick question on sending user input to a div section of an html document.  I asked this question earlier and it seemed to be too broad so I'm going to try to be more specific this time.

I am attempting to send a user input to the div onclick of the send button but every time the code is simply changing the text rather than printing the next text under it.  I'm curious what I'm doing wrong with this.  Thanks for reading and here's my code.

```
<div id="out"</div>
<input type="text" name="textIn" id="txtin">
<input type="button" value="Hit me" onclick="hello()"></input>
<script>
 function hello() {
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById('txtin').value + "<br />"
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/su0o83hj/1/

Comment: `<div id="out"</div>` - Is that your actual code?

Comment: Fix this first: `<div id="out"></div>` then @Jay Buckman answered correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append to the existing text, use += instead of = in the function:

```
function hello() {
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += 
    document.getElementById('txtin').value + "<br />"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i will try to remember this in the future :D

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors, fix it and it will works

```html
<div id="out"></div>
<input type="text" name="textIn" id="txtin" />
<input type="button" value="Hit me" onclick="hello()" />
<script>
 function hello() {
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += 
    document.getElementById('txtin').value + "<br />"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) passing the first parameter `beforeend`:

```js
var out = document.getElementById('out'),
    txtin = document.getElementById('txtin');
    
function hello() {
  out.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', txtin.value + '<br>');
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
<input type="text" name="textIn" id="txtin">
<input type="button" value="Hit me" onclick="hello()">
```